# Objective-C Coding Standards [iPhone/Cocoa]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, coding-style

Are there any generally-accepted coding standards (naming, casting etc) that apply specifically to iPhone/Cocoa/Objective-C? I know Microsoft has published similar standards as they relate to .Net and C# but haven't run across anything related to the iPhone world.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Introduction to Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)

Enjoy!

Comment: Fixed for iPad, but it should redirect on a desktop.

Answer (score 4):

Also take a look at Cocoa Style for Objective-C from Cocoa Dev Central

- [Part I](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php)
- [Part II](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000083.php)

Answer (score 2):

Google also has an [Objective-C style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml)

Answer (score 0):

[The Code Commandments: Best Practices for Objective-C Coding](http://ironwolf.dangerousgames.com/blog/archives/913) is a style guide I can happily endorse.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more Objective-C style guides:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/github/objective-c-conventions)
- [NY Times](https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide)