# How to improve the level of code standards in iPhone Development?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone/Cocoa Coding Standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455384/iphone-cocoa-coding-standards)

I have done some of the applications and my apps are in the AppStore now. But i am always thinking how to write the optimized code and efficient way. What are the thinks will have in the mind, when creating the application. I had some experience also in this development, but Nobody is guiding me, so i am thinking, whether my code is standard formats and optimized. Because in our company they are not following any software principles and MVC structure also. So i want to know, how to plan to developed the apps in the optimized way and want to follow the principles, code standards,etc., Want to improve my level of code standards, So please guide me and give me some feed backs for improved my level of code standards. I donno this is the right place for asking these type of questions, but i want to get some feed backs from experienced peoples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455384/iphone-cocoa-coding-standards) post .It will be very useful.

All the best.