# In what order should class elements be declared in header file?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

I wonder, from both convention and experience stand point, in what order should class elements be declared?

For instance

- class methods
- instance methods
- properties
- something else

What order is "socially acceptable"?

Comment: Cf. [Cocoa coding standards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455384/iphone-cocoa-coding-standards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally the order I use is:

- properties
- class methods
- instance methods
- something else

Comment: Is this a common convention, or is everyone pretty much following their own?

Comment: I think it is common and the way Apple does it, do check the Apple sample code.

Comment: I usually put class methods first as properties represent instance methods or dynamic implementation per instance.  I also list all my iboutlet properties together.

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is personal preference. That said, I haven't seen it done a different way than:

- properties
- class methods
- instance methods

You take them from the most general (properties) to the next largest thing (classes) and then refine down to instance methods. The classes generally make assumptions about the properties which will be set, and the instances methods are dependent on the class methods so the chain goes from most 'meta' to most specific.